# Prevention and cause of SQL Injection (Delay Injection) in ASP.Net_SessionId cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, sql-injection

First Of all I am very new to ASP.Net so please excuse if question is not properly written/ communicated here :-)

We have a ASP.NET website, Some of our Online tester used some "pen-testing tool" to test SQL Injection all over the website..

They provided the result saying that there are some URLs of website where there is a threat of SQL injection...For Example for one of URL they provided that SessionID cookie can modified with a Delay injection (Snap Attached).

Can you guys please let me know what can cause the delay injection to be inserted in cookie and what is its solution.

Already a big thanks to all the champs..
[image]

Comment: What exactly is this "attack" supposed to achieve? And how does it supposedly work?

Comment: It's a cookie, it can be modified, just because it can be modified doesn't mean it can magically cause an attack, the same way that a texbox on your site won't magically cause an attack.

Comment: @JohanP So Is should only validate/care this cookie when I have to use it. Right?

Comment: Yes. There is something called a session fixation attack with respect to this cookie but the code you presented wont do that.